# Can't access Ubuntu web server from local machine

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, port, paster

I'm running python paste http server on port 8087 on Ubuntu 11.10

nmap says 8087/tcp is open

ufw firewall is inactive

But if I pull its local ip up (192.168.1.50:8087) on another local network machine, it cannot connect.

I can ping 192.168.1.50 on the local network machine fine.  I can't telnet into port 8087 though, that tells me something is blocking it?

Been at this for a couple hours 0_o

Any help appreciated

Comment: Is 192.168.1.50 your local machine, or some other machine on the local network?

Comment: 192.168.1.50 would be the server.

Comment: So, you run nmap from your local machine to 192.168.1.50, you can see 8087 listed as open, but if you try to telnet there it doesn't work?

Comment: sorry had that backwards.  192.168.1.50 is the server.  if I run nmap on the server, 8087 is open.

Comment: Ahh, try looking at `netstat -anp | grep 8087` and see whether it's bound to `*:8087` or `127.0.0.1:8087` or `0.0.0.0:8087`?

Comment: it is bound to 127.0.0.1:8087

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it is bound to 127.0.0.1:8087 – Vigrond 46 secs ago

That's your problem. You need to reconfigure your paste server to bind to either `192.168.1.50` or to `0.0.0.0`; `127.0.0.1` is a loopback interface that doesn't accept connections from outside.

Comment: Very nice.  Worked perfectly.  Thanks!  I didn't know that 0_0.  I set it to 0.0.0.0